# How to compare 2 strings in batch and determine if variable is alphabets

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, environment-variables

I have this code

```
for /l %%a in (0, 1, 25) do (
if /i !TextAlphabet!==!Alphabet[%%a]! (
set AlphabetNumber=%%a
)
)
```

`!Alphabet[]!` is an array containing alphabets.

I tried echoing `!TextAlphabet!` and `!Alphabet[%%a]!` and when they are the same, `%AlphabetNumber%` is still the value I set before the loop.

I tried checking for white spaces in my variables but found none.

I also tried adding the variables in a "" tag.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming and belongs on [so].  Try http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @KevinPanko The question is fine here. We allow scripting questions that pertain to power user environments and system administration.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check if a variable contains only letters you could use `findstr`, like this:

```
set var=Abc
echo %var%|findstr "^[A-Za-z]*$" >nul
if %errorlevel% == 0 (echo Variable is alphabetical)
```

### How it works

The variable is echoed and then [piped](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php) to the `findstr` command, which will use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match alphabetical characters:

- `^` matches beginning of line;
- `[A-Za-z]` defines a [character class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) which matches any character from A to Z, both upper case and lower case;
- `*` repeats zero or more occurrences of the previous class;
- `$` matches end of line.

The `%errorlevel%` variable will be set to `0` if there's a match, or `1` otherwise. The `findstr` output will be then redirected to `nul`, thus ignored.

### References

- [Findstr - Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732459.aspx)
- [Findstr - Search for strings | SS64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)